# SVN - want to extract only project name/path and date of commit

Tags: svn

im trying to get an extract with the SVN command line, where i can limit the output to only the project name and the date of the commit.

I dont want to see all file changes and comments.

Anyone know how that can be done without using another program to filter the output of a svn log command ?

Answer (score 0):

Try

`svn info url --xml`

See [doc](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.info.html)

Comment: Does not work. The URL contains multiple folders of different projects, i would like to get a record for each commit with date and which of these projects the commit was made in.

Comment: @LucyRails - can you add some details for your answer? Right now it's not clear - you want the info about url, or list of commits from list of repos